Dynamically-created Select2 options won't save to database (Wordpress + BuddyPress)
I’m using BP XProfile Custom Field Types plugin to add a “Tags” field (select2-based multiselect) to the BuddyPress user profile page.
After the edit profile page loads, I’m dynamically adding new options to my field using this example code from the select2 docs: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items
var data = {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Barn owl'
};

var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
$('#mySelect2').append(newOption).trigger('change');

Everything works perfectly on the frontend. Users are able to see and select my new dynamically-created “Barn Owl” option. Dynamic selection via js works fine too.
But when user hits SAVE CHANGES, any of the selected values that were dynamically-created will not actually save to the database. Only pre-defined or user-typed values actually get saved properly.
Any idea what the problem is or how to resolve? Thanks!

In case it's useful to anyone, the solution was to change the id from an integer to a string. I was thinking id was equivalent to an array key, but in this particular use case it seems like it's more equivalent to an option's "value". So this worked for me:
var data = {
    id: 'Barn owl',
    text: 'Barn owl'
};

